# In PCB track/trace routing, under what situations can acute angles be feasible?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

The 15V power wire routing is as the picture below, it has some acute angles.

[image]

And this is 1.65V wire routing, it even has a 180 degree in the bottom left corner of the picture below.

[image]

This is a FOC driver board made by my teacher who has many PCB project experiences, and the board works well in reality.

It seems the acute angle doesn't matter in some situations, so under what situations can acute angles be feasible?

Comment: Mainly non-RF, non-transmission-line, non-high-voltage arcing stuff.

Comment: You seem to assume that acute angles are an issue in PCB design - can you explain why you think so?

Comment: I feel like there are two issues with acute angles being conflated here: (a) PCB fabrication issue where acute angles get over-etched and (b) transmission line issues where sharp bends can cause signal reflections because of the variation in effective trace width.

Comment: Track angles will matter more depending on frequency, which I can't definitively answer. But I will mention that older methods of PCB production (and perhaps only hobbyist methods) could be affected negatively by right and acute angles because ferric chloride could build up in the corner and make the track thinner than intended in those areas. Modern production methods generally don't have this issue.

Comment: Is it a one-off or mass production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example 1: This is an acute angle in the upper box. With modern manufacturing techniques (and not pushing the limits of the narrowest traces your fab can do) it is not a real problem, although most designers try to avoid it.

There is no acute angle in the lower box. Two oblique or right angles, even separated by 0.1 mm, are not an acute angle.

Example 2: There is no acute angle in two of your three boxes. The blue tracks are on one layer and the red tracks are on another layer. There are a few mils of via between them, and during the etching process (which is done separately for each layer, before any holes are drilled in the board) there is no chance for etchant to be caught in the angle between them.

In the upper left box there is an acute angle between the red track and the pad around the via:

[image: ![enter image description here]

As mentioned before, this is not a problem with modern manufacturing methods, but most PCB designers nonetheless avoid such angles.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the transmission line effects and Telegrapher's Equations with the Return Loss and emissions of high gradient E-field's  this may be noticable for phase above 1 decade below the 1/4 wavelength or 10% . And considering the speed inverse is 5ns/m or 5ps/mm unless there is any spectrum or rise time 10 x the propagation time in the trace path, there is no noticeable effect of high gradient E-field for EMI or crosstalk or return loss.

### Recommendation

Consider reducing sharp edges for risetimes less than 1ns and ensure impedances are controlled. This is equivalent to BW>300 MHz.

High power Return Losses for transmitters at lower freq. will need controlled impedances but less concern for sharp edges like SMPS operating at 1MHz with over 50 MHz are unlikely to be concerned about sharp corners, nor WiFi antenna with zigzags can use sharp corners.

Crosstalk by mutual coupling of inductance or capacitance of traces is of much greater importance and is easily computed on Saturn PCB design tool. (Windows free)

Mathematical proof requires some susceptible or emissive specifications for EMI, so this is just a "rule of thumb"

Comment: What does this have to do with OP's question about routing power supply tracks?

Comment: @ThePhoton Your question implies you do not understand my answer that explains why acute angles are irrelevant like your question.  DRC will tell you if your clearances are inadequate.  Gaps are simple geometry.